# Show hidden div on change of a select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a select field with ID `#dailywardentry-ipd_patient_id` and a div with id and class like this
`<div id ="div2" class="hidden">`

I am also using CSS to keep the div hidden on load
like
`.hidden { display: none; }`
I am using this function to show the div on change of the select field as above.
The div is hidden on load, but should show on change.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $("#dailywardentry-ipd_patient_id").on("change", function(){
        $("#div2").removeClass('hidden');;
    });
});
</script>
```

What I am doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: Well posting the full html is difficult, it is quite long - but I am putting here just the beginning - `<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>        </div>
        <div  class="col-lg-12">
            <div id ="div2" class="hidden">
            
  <div id="w1">`

Comment: Actually it was the select that I was more interested in. Also, please edit the question with changes instead of posting them as comments.

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/orhq3x90/ So open your JS console (F12) and tell us what errors you get.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Ok in firbug - I am getting the error -`ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 

$(function(){

 `

Comment: That means you're not loading jQuery.

Comment: You need to add the jQuery library to your page `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>` before your script.

Comment: @blex -Error is gone after including the JQuery libray, but the div is stil not shown

Comment: Again, please post a complete code example. Include a jsFiddle showing the issue as well if you like. What you've provided so far isn't enough.

Comment: Thanks to all of you nice guys for confirming that the code is OK, there is some other issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think there is some conflict in jQuery library as I am working in Yii2 framework, where it loads it own jQuery.

I get it done using this code:

```
<?php
$this->registerJs("$('#dailywardentry-ipd_patient_id').on('change', function(){
        $('#div2').removeClass('hidden');    

});"); 
?>
```